# Cosa significa "a sganascio"?

Tags: meaning

Nella versione in italiano dell'episodio *La nascita del giullare* di *Mistero buffo*, di Dario Fo, ho letto:

> No, e nemmeno è successo che mia madre, guardandomi bambino spaparanzato nella culla che ridevo **a sganascio**, abbia esclamato: «Ma che bella faccina simpatica... Allegria mi fai!, pagliacciolino ridente! Guarda, da grande ti faccio fare il giullare!»

Non so cosa significa "a sganascio".
Ho cercato il vocabolo "sganascio" su parecchi dizionari,  ma non l'ho trovato. Sapreste spiegarmelo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esiste l'espressione "*sganasciarsi dalle risate*" (vedi http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sganasciare/) che significa appunto ridere talmente tanto da slogarsi la mascella. Qui "*a sganascio*" ha un significato analogo; significa che il bimbo nella culla rideva tanto e di gusto.

Esiste anche l'espressione "*ridere a crepapelle*".